# Gabor Filter problem

Tags: matlab, time-frequency

How to design a Gabor Filter for pattern recognition. I just cannot figure it.

Comment: See [Gabor Filter](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23253) from FEX for inspiration.

Comment: A good question shows that some research effort has gone into it. Your question as it stands is rather vague.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The links i am providing will clear will clear your basics about GABOR FILTER as well as get you started on PATTERN RECOGNITION

1. [Basics of gabor filter](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~arul/report/node13.html)
2. [Visualization of GABOR Filter](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2005/cmsc838s/assignment-projects/gabor-filter-visualization/report.pdf)
3. [Check these for Pattern recognition](http://iwi.eldoc.ub.rug.nl/FILES/root/1999/ProcICIAPKruizinga/1999ProcICIAPKruizinga.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

You can find a Matlab implementation of the Gabor Filter in the Wikipedia article about the [Gabor Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter#Example_implementation). That should get you started.